# What exactly is virtualEnv isolating? Just python related packages or more?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I create a new virtualEnv, if I install Django inside a new environment, it's isolated.
But what if I'm inside a virtualEnv and I install emacs, and mysql or such. These packages have nothing to do with python.  Would the emacs and mysql packages that I installed be global or isolated to one virtualEnv only?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only python packages installed inside virtualenvironment are isolated.
System packages are not.